# Encontrar un camino entre dos nodos en un grafo orientado Python3

Tags: python, teoría-de-grafos

Me piden implementar una función camino(g,x,y) en Python que devuelva una lista de los vértices que representan un posible camino para ir de x a y mediante el grafo ORIENTADO g. NO PUEDO USAR CONTRUCTORES DE CLASE GRAFO, en mi caso g=(E,V) donde E=[x_0,...,x_n-1] es la lista de vértices (n natural cualquiera) y V=[a_0,...,a_m-1] a_j=(x_s,x_t) es la lista de aristas (representados por tuplas para un m cualquiera).

El grafo orientado que me pasen puede ser CÍCLICO, es decir, puede tener un arista (x_s,x_t) y otro (x_t,x_s).

Si me pasan camino(g,x,x) devuelvo list(x) y si me pasan camino(g,x,y) donde x o y no están en E, devuelvo [].

He probado el siguiente código pero no funciona para todos los casos que he intentado y se me ocurre que las listas con generadores pueden ayudar pero no sé cómo.

```
def camino(g,x,y):
    #g=(V,E) : V = [x1,...,xn] E \subset VxV
    E = g[0]
    res = [x]
    if ( x not in E or y not in E ) :
        return []
    elif ( x == y ) :
        return list(x)
    else :
        V = g[1]
        m = len(V)
        res = [x]
        while y != x :
            for i in range(m):
                a = V[i]
                if x == a[0] and a[1] not in res :
                    x = a[1]
                    res += [x]
                    break
    return res
```

Sólo os puedo compartir un ejemplo que me dan `camino((['a','b','c','d'],[('a','b'),('b','a'),('b','c'),('c','a')]),'a','c')` devuelve `['a','b','c']` ya que desde 'a' puedo pasar a 'b' mediante ('a','b') y desde esta a 'c' mediante ('b','c'). Pero para este ejemplo mi código funciona. En cambio, he probado casos más complicados y falla.

Por ejemplo con :
`E = ['a','b','c','d'] V = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('a','d'),('d','a'),('c','b'),('d','b'),('c','d'),('d','c'),('a','c'),('c','a')]`
No consigo pasar de la segunda invocación de :

`print(camino((E,V),'a','b'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'a','c'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'a','d'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'b','a'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'b','c'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'b','d'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'c','a'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'c','b'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'c','d'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'d','a'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'d','b'))`
`print(camino((E,V),'d','c'))`

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega un juego de datos de prueba y el resultado que se debe obtener con ellos. Asi será posible verificar la corrección de las respuestas.

Comment: Dices: "_El grafo orientado que me pasen puede ser CÍCLICO, es decir, puede tener un arista (x_s,x_t) y otro (x_t,x_s)._"  Y pregunto yo ¿puede contener ciclos mayores? Ej: x1->x2->x3->x4->x1?

Comment: Y has dado alguna estrategia de backtracking para este tipo de cosas? El algoritmo A* o algo así? O tienes que resolverlo por fuerza bruta o inventar tú el algoritmo?

Comment: Claro, podría ser que contuviera ciclos mayores dado que no me dan ninguna restricción sobre el grafo g.  Sobre el segundo comentario, no, no he dado nada absolutamente de grafos

Comment: Y sobre recursividad? Tengo una posible solución recursiva y para el ejemplo que has dado sale lo mismo, pero me gustaría probarlo con más ejemplos, en particular con alguno de esos "complicados" para los que dices que te falla.

Comment: Pues la verdad es que he borrado los ejemplos que había propuesto pero no tengo más ejemplos en principio, los voy metiendo a mano. Recursiva sería genial

Answer (score 1):

A continuación propongo una solución que usa "fuerza bruta" y recursividad. Es decir, va explorando todas las rutas posibles según el conjunto de conexiones E, y se detiene cuando alcanza el nodo destino. Si llega a un "callejón sin salida" (un nodo que no es el destino y desde el cual ya no puede moverse porque todos sus vecinos ya han sido visitados), entonces "deshace sus pasos" (elimina el nodo de la ruta) para probar otra vía (esto se denomina *backtracking*).

El método no garantiza encontrar la ruta más corta posible, pues se detiene en cuanto encuentra una. Pudiera ser que más adelante, en el conjunto E encontrara una ruta más directa (quizás había una conexión ('x', 'y') justo al final de E, pero si antes encontró otra ruta, aunque fuera más larga, retornará la primera que encuentre).

Para simplificar la implementación he escrito un generador que va dando uno a uno cada uno de los vecinos de un nodo que le pases como parámetro.

He intentado explicar con detalle cómo funciona todo en los propios comentarios del código, pero puedo extenderme más en lo que resulte más confuso.

```py
def vecinos(g, x):
  # Esta función recibe el grafo (g) y un nodo (x), y retorna
  # todos los vecinos de ese nodo. Es una función generadora
  # por lo que puede usarse en un bucle for como hace luego
  # la función camino_recursivo()
  V, E = g
  for orig, dst in E:
    if orig == x:
      yield dst

def camino_recursivo(g, x, y, visitados, ruta):
  # Esta función recibe el grafo (g), el punto en que estamos en un 
  # momento dado (x) y el punto al que queremos llegar (y) junto con 
  # el conjunto "visitados" que son los nodos por los que ya hemos pasado, 
  # y la lista "ruta" que es la ruta recorrida hasta este momento

  # Añadir el nodo actual a la ruta y a los visitados
  ruta.append(x)
  visitados.add(x)

  # Para cada uno de los vecinos del nodo actual
  for vecino in vecinos(g, x):
    # Si ya había sido visitado lo saltamos
    if vecino in visitados:
      continue

    # Si es el destino, hemos encontrado una ruta
    if vecino == y:
      ruta.append(y)
      return True

    # Si no es el destino buscamos (recursivamente) una ruta
    # desde el vecino hasta el destino
    if camino_recursivo(g, vecino, y, visitados, ruta):
      # Y si la encontramos retornamos true
      return True
  
  # Si llegamos aqui es que hemos agotado los vecinos sin encontrar una
  # ruta que lleve al destino. Así que este nodo x no era buena opción
  # lo quitamos de la ruta (backtracking)
  ruta.pop(-1)
  return False


def camino(g, x, y):
  # Esta es la función que nos piden, que hará uso de la recursiva
  # Imprimimos la intención de llegar de x a y
  print(f"{x!r} -> {y!r}", end=": ")

  # Primero tratamos casos triviales (que no estén la lista de nodos
  # o que x ya sea el destino)
  if ( x not in g[0] or y not in g[0] ) :
      return []
  elif ( x == y ) :
      return [x]

  # Si no era un caso trivial, construimos una ruta vacía y un conjunto
  # vacío de nodos visitados
  ruta = []
  visitados = set()

  # Y se los pasamos a la solución recursiva. Si ésta retorna true
  # en la ruta (que la propia función ha ido modificando) estará
  # la solución. Si retorna False es que no hay ruta posible
  if camino_recursivo(g, x, y, visitados, ruta):
    return ruta
  else:
    return []
```

### Tests

El caso sencillo:

```
camino((['a','b','c','d'],[('a','b'),('b','a'),('b','c'),('c','a')]),'a','c')
---
'a' -> 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Un caso sin solución:

```
camino((['a','b','c','d'],[('a','b'),('b','a'),('b','f'),('a', 'x'), ('c','a')]),'a','c')
---
'a' -> 'c': []
```

Tu batería de tests (todos con solución aunque se observa cómo en algunos casos, al quedarse con la primera ruta que encuentra, no ve que había otra más corta):

```
print(camino((E,V),'a','b'))
print(camino((E,V),'a','c'))
print(camino((E,V),'a','d'))
print(camino((E,V),'b','a'))
print(camino((E,V),'b','c'))
print(camino((E,V),'b','d'))
print(camino((E,V),'c','a'))
print(camino((E,V),'c','b'))
print(camino((E,V),'c','d'))
print(camino((E,V),'d','a'))
```

Resultado:

```
'a' -> 'b': ['a', 'b']
'a' -> 'c': ['a', 'd', 'c']
'a' -> 'd': ['a', 'd']
'b' -> 'a': ['b', 'a']
'b' -> 'c': ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c']
'b' -> 'd': ['b', 'a', 'd']
'c' -> 'a': ['c', 'b', 'a']
'c' -> 'b': ['c', 'b']
'c' -> 'd': ['c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
'd' -> 'a': ['d', 'a']
'd' -> 'b': ['d', 'a', 'b']
'd' -> 'c': ['d', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
def camino(g, inicio, fin, visitados = None):
    #g=(V,E) : V = [x1,...,xn] E \subset VxV
    vertices = g[0]
    aristas = g[1]

    if not visitados:
        visitados = []

    visitados.append(inicio)
    if inicio == fin:
        return visitados

    ''' Seleccionar todas las aristas que contengan x como primer elemento
        y que no hayan sido visitadas 
    '''
    seleccion = [x for x in aristas if x[0] == inicio and x[1] not in visitados]
    resultado = []
    for arista in seleccion:
        ''' Probar cada vertice conectado con el actual '''
        if resultado := camino(g, arista[1], fin, visitados):
            break
    else:
        ''' Ninguno de los vertices conectados lleva a destino '''
        visitados.pop()

    return resultado
```

El algoritmo es entrar y colocar de inmediato el nodo inicial en la lista de visitados, a la vez que chequear la condición de término, que es cuando el inicio es igual al fin. Cuando se cumple la condición de término, se retorna la lista de vértices visitados (o una lista vacia, en caso contrario).

```
visitados.append(inicio)
if inicio == fin:
    return visitados
```

Si no se ha llegado al destino, se seleccionan las aristas conectadas al vértice actual que no hayan sido visitadas aún

```
seleccion = [x for x in aristas if x[0] == inicio and x[1] not in visitados]
```

Esta es la lista de potenciales rutas al destino, que se recorren en un ciclo, comprobando recursivamente si alguna de ellas sirve. Si es así, rompemos el ciclo. En `resultado` tenemos la ruta completa a estas alturas.

Si el ciclo termina sin encontrar una ruta vía este vértice, lo sacamos de la lista de nodos visitados y retornamos una lista vacia.

**Notas**

La lista `visitados` se construye dentro de la función y se traspasa de una llamada a otra.

En la declaración de la función aparece inicializada con `None`, no con la lista vacía `[]`. La lista se inicializa adentro:

```
if not visitados:
    visitados = []
```

para asegurar que en cada nuevo problema la lista comience vacía.

#### Demo

```
z = camino((['a','b','c','d'],[('a','b'),('b','a'),('b','c'),('c','a')]),'a','c')
print("Camino a -> c", z)

E = ['a','b','c','d']
V = [('a','b'), ('b','a'), ('a','d'), ('d','a'), ('c','b'), ('d','b'), ('c','d'), ('d','c'), ('a','c'),('c','a')]
z = camino((E, V), 'b', 'c')
print("Camino b -> c", z)

z = camino((E, V), 'a', 'c')
print("Camino a -> c", z)
```

produce:

```
Camino a -> c ['a', 'b', 'c']
Camino b -> c ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c']
Camino a -> c ['a', 'd', 'c']
```